# Access WooCommerce Order Details in Custom Plugin

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, woocommerce-bookings

i'm guessing this is a simple thing that I can't seem to wrap my head around. I'm trying to write a little custom plugin that requires grabbing the data of a order made in WooCommerce & WooCommerce Bookings. The issue i'm having though is that nothing seems to be returning when I run the function:

```
function middleground_function(){

    $order = wc_get_order(37340);

    print_r($order);
}



add_action( 'woocommerce_after_register_post_type ', 'middleground_function' );
```

I don't get any errors but I don't get any print. So i'm wondering what i'm missing here!

When it goes to production that action will change to woocommerce_payment_complete but I figured i'd be able to atleast test it with a test ID

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure why you are using the `woocommerce_after_register_post_type` action hook. but if you want just to test whether you can get order details by id or not you can use the `init` hook. try the below code.

```
function middleground_function(){
    $order = wc_get_order( 37340 );
    echo "<pre>"; print_r( $order ); echo "</pre>";
}
add_action( 'init ', 'middleground_function' );
```

Comment: Hey there thanks! I used after_register as I saw another comment on here saying when to do it. Thanks for your answer! Unfortuantely init still isn't working; nothing gets returned :(

Comment: Edit: Init wasn't working until I added a "echo "test";" line after the print_r...thats odd